# Skobbler add custom POIs to heatmap

Tags: ios, objective-c, skmaps

I'm looking for a way to add POIs to SKMapView heat map which are generated from my app. In the example provided with SDK there's only a way to show categories from internal data source.

I looked at category from SKMaps SDK and there're only two methods:

```
@interface SKMapView (HeatMaps)

- (void)showHeatMapWithPOIType:(NSArray *)poiTypes;
- (void)clearHeatMap;

@end
```

Also I have another question: how to set minimal and maximal zoom level for heat maps?

As an alternative I'm looking for a way to add custom overlay like in Apple Maps:

```
[self.mapView addOverlay:self.heatMap];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently heat maps work only with OSM POI types - generating heat maps from a custom POI data set is on the roadmap in the second part of 2015

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I also noticed that heatmaps are available from certain zoom level. Could you also add a setting for minimal zoom level from which heatmaps are visible.

Comment: Any updates here? There's plenty of reference code available - https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=heatmap+swift+mapkit&type=Code&ref=searchresults

Comment: It didn't get it for the 3.0 release. Next year we'll look into this