# Add custom POIs in navigation mode

Tags: android, skmaps

I am using skobbler SDK. I already added custom POIs in "normal" map view mode. But I would like to use custom POIs to display while navigating a route. But `mapView.addCustomPOIs(skMapCustomPOIs);` does not work when I am in navigation mode. Here one can read that adding custom POIs is not possible on heatmap:

[Skobbler add custom POIs to heatmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28323245/skobbler-add-custom-pois-to-heatmap)

Is this also right for navigation mode?

Answer (score 2):

[SKPOITrackerManager](http://developer.skobbler.com/docs/android/com/skobbler/ngx/poitracker/SKPOITrackerManager.html) is used for tracking points of interest during a navigation.  You can provides the POIs to the tracker & will be notified which POIs are detected, based on a set of custom detection rules. SKPOITrackerManager works during a navigation session only.

Comment: I am now using SKPOITrackerManager. But I see that I have to draw POIs manually. In your demo I can see you doing that with annotations. Isn't it possible to draw the images automatically on POI detection? I mean the images which are used when NearBySearch is made. Using SKSearchListener each SKSearchResult has a category- Furthermore I have a bigger problem: If I use these settings: ``poiTrackerManager.startPOITrackerWithRadius(100, 0.5);`` and I try to get many POIs received by ``onReceivedPOIs`` then only one POI is returned although there should be more regarding to their coordinates.

Comment: Maybe it seems that only those POIs are found which are placed directly on the route. Currently I have no rules set. But I already had some settings given by ``setAerialDistance(int aerialDistance)`` and ``setRouteDistance(int routeDistance)``. So how can that be?

Comment: The "tracked POI" and the visual POI as disjoint - you could have a hidden tracked POI or a visual POI that is not "tracked" - so if you want to have a POI on the map and also track it you would have to "code" it twice. As for the detection rules - the rules have a logic "AND" between them, with every condition having a "default" value - most probably the combination of these default values makes it so only certain POIs (which are on route) to be detected. I recommend that you start a new question where you include your current detection settings, so that I can look into it